# Have multiple names in a column, need to create a row for each one

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe in which I have a column with multiple values (column A), I need to create a row for each value in this column keeping the data from the other columns (column B and others)

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Xbox, Playstation | Xbox Elite 2, Dualsense Edge |
| Xbox, Nintendo, Atlus | Persona 3 Portable, Persona 4 Golden |

I'm expecting something like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Xbox | Xbox Elite 2, Dualsense Edge |
| Playstation | Xbox Elite 2, Dualsense Edge |
| Xbox | Persona 3 Portable, Persona 4 Golden |
| Nintendo | Persona 3 Portable, Persona 4 Golden |
| Atlus | Persona 3 Portable, Persona 4 Golden |

I know this can be done manually, but I want to know if there is a way to do it with python, I have around 400 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it, convert the values to a list and then explode into rows

```
# split the column on , which makes the content of columnA as a list
df['Column A']=df['Column A'].str.strip().str.split(',' )

# explode
out=df.explode(['Column A'])
out
```

```
    Column A        Column B
0   Xbox            Xbox Elite 2, Dualsense Edge
0   Playstation     Xbox Elite 2, Dualsense Edge
1   Xbox            Persona 3 Portable, Persona 4 Golden
1   Nintendo        Persona 3 Portable, Persona 4 Golden
1   Atlus           Persona 3 Portable, Persona 4 Golden
```

Comment: I just had to delethe the "[ ]" in the explode process, but it was really hepfull. Thank you for the help!